Entity Framework Core: Passing a function to a Where and doing a Select will construct the object?
I am running into a very confusing issue with querying data in EF Core, and hoping that I can find the answer here.
I have School and Student entities that are mapped to the tables with the same name in database. There is a one to many association between them(School has many students).
When I do:
Func<Student, bool> whereClause = s => s.School!=null; 
var studentNames = efContext.Students.Where(whereClause).Select(s=>s.Name).ToList();

It is trying to instantiate the Student class, where I am only doing a select for name.
But when I do the following:
var studentNames = efContext.Students.Where(s => s.School!=null).Select(s=>s.Name).ToList();

It doesn't create a new instance of the Student class.
What is the difference here?
My expectation is that, in either case instance of the Student class shouldn't be created.

The second case is actually compiled down to an Expression that linq can parse to sql. The first one can't readily do the conversion and must pull down the objects first.

Instead of using a Func try building an Expression and see if you get the same behavior.

See the first duplicate. The first query first executes efContext.Students and then applies the where function on the materialized result. The second query is translated all the way to SQL.

I believe you need to wrap the Func in an Expression in order for Entity Framework to work its magic. So
Expression<Func<Student, bool>> whereClause = s => s.School != null;

Also, assuming Student has a foreign key, SchoolId, to a School, you will probably get better results from
Expression<Func<Student, bool>> whereClause = s => s.SchoolId != null;

The latter expression translates to SQL relatively easily — not sure how "is the navigation property null" from the former expression translates (which might be why it's instantiating the School object — you're no longer in "SQL mode").
Possibly helpful: What's the purpose of the Expression class?

This. An Expression is VERY different from a Func, even though their code representations are the same.

@Alejandro That was my assumption, but I've never really had to become an expert on the difference, so I wasn't sure how to explain something that just kinda... intuitively?... makes sense to me, when I've needed to build expressions in past projects. Glad Gert Arnold knows better references.
